# Hibernate - spring annotated entities not scanned from within jar

Tags: hibernate, spring

I have a package containing annotated entity classes that I import into my web project.
When tomcat deploys the project the entity class that are in the jar are not scanned for annotations. is there a way to tell spring to search for annotated classes inside a jar file? i.e. :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="{path to jar or something}"/>
```

Comment: I forgot to add - I am using maven to create the jars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean `@Entity` annotated classes, `<context:component-scan>` has nothing to do with them. `@Entity` classes are discovered by Hibernate, so you need to configure Hibernate, not Spring.

If you use Hibernate via JPA (i.e. you have `persistence.xml`), you need to add the following line to `persistence.xml` in order to scan `/WEB-INF/lib/yourFileWithEntities.jar` for entity classes:

```
<jar-file>lib/yourFileWithEntities.jar</jar-file>
```

Comment: I had to add <jar-file>WEB-INF/lib/my-package-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar-file> in order for it to work..

Answer (score 8):

Look for:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html

the second example:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.package"/>
</bean>
```

Put two wildcards behind to scan all subpackages. (ex: "test.package.**")

Comment: For Hibernate 4: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean does the job :)

Answer (score 1):

use spring3.1,or use `<class>com.***.***<class>`tag to add entity class in your persistence.xml.