# When to use Spring @Autowire annotation

Tags: spring, jpa, entity, autowired

Recently I had discussion with my friend regarding usage of `Spring @Autowire` annotation on entity(`JPA`) classes.

In our project we are using `@Autowire` annotaion to inject `Entity` but my friend suggesting not to use `@Autowire` annotaions on entity classes. When I asked why? He dont have the proper answer for that. So i just wanted to know are there any disadvantages using `@Autowire` annotaion on entity classes.

Also please explain when to go for `@Autowire` annotaion or not with example.

Thank in advance.

Comment: My project is integration of JSF,JPA and SPRING and getting company object in controller by *@Autowire*.

Entiy class
*@Entity*
*@Table(name="T_Company")*
class Company{}

Controller class
class CompanyController{
// wthin this i am using entity calls 
*@Autowire*
Company company;
// i do other opertions
}

application-bean.xml
<bean id="company" class="xxx.Company"/>

and i have defined the entity in 
Persistence.xml
<class>xxx.Company</class>

In My CompanyController is it preferable to use @Autowire Compnay or i have to use Company c=new Company() and which one to use and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Entity and @Autowire are not interchangeable.

@Entity annotation indicates that the JavaBean is a persistent entity.This is actually a JPA annotation and not a Spring Annotation.
@Entity will be used in the sessionFactory by the packagesToScan poroerty.

@Autowired:  inject a resource by-type, i.e. by the class or by the interface of the annotated field or contractor.  See my answer [Inject and Resource and Autowired annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450902/inject-and-resource-and-autowired-annotations/20451954#20451954)
@Autowired is used to inject dependencies as an alternative to setting it via xml configurations

Maybe this answer will help you understand 
[Hibernate - spring annotated entities not scanned from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980582/hibernate-spring-annotated-entities-not-scanned-from-within-jar)

**UPDATE:**
Following the comment bellow:
Company is your domain object, so you don't need to use spring in this case.

```
<bean id="company" class="xxx.Company"/>
```

The above will return the same instance with @autowire.
Even if you switch to scope="prototype" I don't see any reason to use spring for that.
You should have a service that will be used to CRUD company e.g. 
CompanyService, this service will be a single tone so you will use @Autowire to inject it to the controller and it will use your JPA framework to implement CRUD's

To create a new company you will use:

```
Company c = new Company  //this probably will  be binded from your ui form 
companyServic.saveOrUpdate(c);
```

See the following answer [spring rest service - hibernate dao - annotations - pojo - namedqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288364/spring-rest-service-hibernate-dao-annotations-pojo-namedqueries/19288761#19288761). 
For common practice of DAO and services.

Comment: My project is integration of JSF,JPA and SPRING and getting company object in controller by *@Autowire*

Entity class
*@Entity*
*@Table(name="T_Company")*
class Company{}

and i have controller calss like
class CompanyController{
// wthin this i am using entity calls 
*@Autowire*
Company company;
// i do other opertions
}

application-bean.xml
<bean id="company" class="xxx.Company"/>

and i have defined the entity in 
Persistence.xml
<class>xxx.Company</class>

In CompanyController is it preferable to use @Autowire Compnay or use Company c=new Company() and which one to use and why?

Answer (score 2):

@Autowire is an annotation used to perform a dependency injection, its almost similar to the standard @Inject you can take a look at the spring reference manual to see the difference between those two annotations.

@Entity is a part of the jpa framework its used to mark a class as persistent, spring does not implement an equivalent annotation.